# Printing all numbers from N to M in one single expression

Tags: rosetta-stone

Given the integers N and M, can you print all numbers from N to M comma-seperated? The hitch is to use one single expression.

The output for *N=23* and *M=42* should look like this:

```
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42
```

I'll start with Ruby:

```
puts (23..42).to_a.join(', ')
```

Comment: related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8588/return-each-number-from-a-group-of-numbers/

Comment: @ardnew The special catch of my task is that the solution has to be achieved using only one expression, which is way harder and probably not possible in every language. I don't consider your link as related.

Comment: @YMMD what do you consider a single expression in golfscript?

Comment: I thought of a nested expression which still could be a code gold issue, but indeed I get your point. I deleted the `code-golf`-tag.

Comment: so now that the code golf tag has been removed, is there even an objective or winning criteria anymore?

Comment: Quite poorly worded task. As you can see the answers, there are too many variations: `n..m` vs `23..42`, “,” vs “, ”, quoted vs unquoted output, maybe with or without trailing separator. I know, it is not [tag:code-golf] anymore, but I think the answer still should be somehow comparable.

Comment: @manatwork, that's the least of its problems. The biggest problem is that, as Jan pointed out, "expression" is not well defined.

Comment: @JanDvorak Single expression in golfscript? `"#{(23..42).to_a.join(', ')}"` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## k

17 chars. Expression returns 1 but prints output to `stdout`

```
1@", "/:$23_!1+42
```

To return a string with the comma seperated values, simply use:

```
", "/:$23_!1+42
```

Answer (score 2):

### Sage CLI, 14

Edit: Sage has a `range` shorthand.

```
`[n..m]`[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 63 bytes

```
puts "$n,[join [lmap a [lrepeat [expr {$m-$n}] 0] {incr n}] ,]"
```

Comment: My answer has the problem of putting new lines: `while {$n<$m} {puts $n,;incr n};puts $m`

Comment: Fixed: `while {$n<$m} {lappend l $n,;incr n};lappend l $m;puts $l`

Comment: OK I forgot there is the requirement of 1 single expression; my answers are not acceptable!

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 21 bytes

```
echo {23..42}|tr \  ,
```

Comment: what about `seq -s, 23 42`

Comment: @marcosm `seq` is distribution specific and not available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby: 18 characters

```ruby
$><<[*23..42]*", "
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -e '$><<[*23..42]*", "'
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42
```

### Forcing the rules: 10 characters

As seen in the other answers:

- variables instead of numeric literals
- comma only instead of comma and space
- no output, just generated value

```ruby
[*n..m]*?,
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> n=23
=> 23

irb(main):002:0> m=42
=> 42

irb(main):003:0> [*n..m]*?,
=> "23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python: 39

```
print(",".join(map(str,range(23,42))))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### J, 28 characters

```
echo(,', ',])&":/[23}.i.>:42
```

- `i.43` creates an array of 43 values `0..42`. Unfortunately, we have to compute `43`.
- `23}.` drops first 23 of them, leaving `23..42`. If precomputation is allowed, `23+i.20` fares better byte-wise (-3 characters)
- `,', ',]` concatenates both arguments with `', '` between them
- `...&":` does that after converting both arguments to strings
- `.../` does that as a reduction step.
- `echo` is a built-in to perform standard output. If simply returning is enough, you can drop this (-4 characters)

Answer (score 0):

### R: 17 characters

```
cat(n:m,sep=", ")
```

Example:

```
> n=23
> m=42
> cat(n:m,sep=", ")
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42
```