# Compact a list of numbers

Tags: code-golf, string

Inspired by [Using LaTeX to compact a list of numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326115/7734), this challenge is to output a compact list of numbers, given a range, as follows:

```
Input: 1,2, 3,4,5,8,11, 12,13
Output: 1-5, 8, 11-13

Input: 20,21,45,56,75, 76,77,78
Output: 20-21, 45, 56, 75-78

Input: 4,5
Output: 4-5
```

Input is always comma separated numbers, sometimes with spacing, and output should be in the format above -- note space after the commas. There is no upper limit to the length of the input string.

Winner: Smallest in terms of bytes

Comment: This is a nice first challenge :). Sadly, apart from sorting the array, it's the exact same challenge as [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52321/34388).