# Continuous Port Ranges

Tags: code-golf

### Background

Network discovery tool Nmap takes a list of TCP/UDP port numbers as input and performs a security audit against the listed ports. The target port listing on the command line includes selected port numbers as strings separated by a comma. To make specifying big amounts of ports more convenient the tool also supports specifying closed numeric ranges by giving the first and last port number separated by a dash. Leaving out either the first or last number will create an open ended range. However port 0 has a special meaning and is never included in an open range unless it is the starting point.

### Task

Your task is to write a program that receives a sorted list of 16-bit unsigned integers ( 0 - 65535 ) and produces the shortest possible string following continuous range specification from above.

### Test Cases

The test inputs have been shortened below to make their size manageable. For example the test input `[0, 3, 4, 5, 8]` would be presented below as `[0, 3..5, 8]`. A program submitted as a solution must work on the fully expanded list/array `[0, 3, 4, 5, 8]` and does not need to support expanding abbreviated inputs.

```
[22] -> "22"
[22, 25, 80] -> "22,25,80"
[80..85, 443, 8000..8005, 8080..8085] -> "80-85,443,8000-8005,8080-8085"
[1..100, 60000..65535] -> "-100,60000-"
[1..65535] -> "-"
[0..65535] -> "0-"
```

### Scoring

Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Might an input require us to merge two or more given ranges to be shorter, like `22..30,31.35,36` to `22-36`? If so, I'd suggest adding some test cases covering various possibilities.

Comment: @xnor the input is a single flat array, not an array of arrays

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean that, say `80..85` in the test cases is a shorthand for the six numbers actually in the input list?

Comment: @xnor I added an explanation for the shorthand to the "test cases" section

Comment: Seconding xnor, following the update it still isn't clear whether the input is verbatim `[0, 3..5, 8]` or `[0, 3, 4, 5, 8]`?

Comment: @Etheryte I rewrote the explanation, I hope it is clear now

Comment: Does [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52321/80214) answer your question? The only difference is the open-ended range edge cases.

Comment: If I needed an answer, I would not be posting on Code Golf. I guess we will find out if people are interested in doing a similar but slightly more difficult challenge.

Comment: Actually it seems to be so close to this challenge that I decided to mark this as a duplicate question.